# To what extent do page's ranks influence each other?

Tags: ranking, google-ranking

Regarding optimization, does Google look at all the pages on a site and calculate a site rank? Or does it only rank pages? Or a bit of both, in which case, to what extent?

As an example, in a website of well-optimized pages and posts, can a slow-loading, or un-informative homepage drag the rank of other well-optimised individual pages and posts down with it? If so, to what extent?

Or the reverse scenario: let's say I have 90 badly-optimized pages, and 10 pages with great optimization. Will those 90 pages drag down the 10 good ones? If I deleted the 90, would it improve the 10?

To keep the question neutral and specific, perhaps link juice - internal and inbound - should be kept out of the equation. Ranking purely based on content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses both page level signals and site level signals in their ranking algorithms.   It is certainly possible for some bad pages to cause everything on your site to rank worse.  Google's Panda algorithm is a prime example of that.   When a site has many low quality pages, the entire site stops ranking well.

When you say that a page is not "optimized", I wouldn't necessarily worry too much about that.  Having pages that don't target keywords well, or don't use titles aren't going to hurt the other pages on your site.     As long as a page is useful to your visitors, it is unlikely to negatively effect the rest of your site.

I would worry about pages that:

- Are spammy -- Google will penalize an entire site when they find hidden text or other spam even on one page.
- Have thin content -- Google's Panda algorithm penalizes entire sites when many pages don't fully cover the topic.
- Are very poor quality -- Pages riddled with spelling errors, bad grammar, or factual errors are likely to send users elsewhere.   Google notices when users don't like a page.   It reflects badly on the whole site.
- Have usability issues -- similar to poor quality, if users can't use the page, they return back to the Google search results and click on something else.   Google takes note of that.